# Roller Coaster Physics/Math CAP contest question?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

An object is released from rest at a height h. For the
object to go around the loop (of radius r) what is the
smallest possible value of h?
Assume the roller coaster track is frictionless.

Comment: How many of thesee contest questions are you going to ask?

Comment: All the ones I couldn't get

Answer (score 0):

for complete loop, $v=\sqrt{5gr}$
 simply applying Conservation of energy,
$$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

we get $v=\frac{5}{2}gr$.